# Scroll issue with multiple ui-ace code editors

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Using ui-ace http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-ace/ and trying to use multiple code editors in a single web page.  plunker example is here https://plnkr.co/GPictv3HdtGWW76fHw2l

You should be able to reproduce the scroll issue by following these steps:

1. Scroll down to code editor4 and select some text in editor4
2. Scroll up to code editor1 and select some text in editor1
3. Scroll back to code editor4 and when you click in code editor4 to select or edit text the window auto scrolls up to show code editor1

The main code to display the editors 1 - 4 is here.  How can I prevent the auto scrolling behavior?  If a user clicks in one of the code editors to edit or select text the window should not scroll to a different code editor.  If I change the height in `style.css` to 70px instead of 500px then all code editors fit within the the browser window when maximized and the auto scrolling issue doesn't occur when selecting or editing code in the different code editors.  if you shrink your browser window height so the code editors don't fit within the window then the scroll issue will begin to occur again as you try to select or edit code in the different code editors.

```
<section>
<label>Editor1:</label>
<div ui-ace="{
  useWrapMode : false,
  showGutter: false,
  theme:'monokai',
  mode: 'javascript'
}" ng-model="editor1">Ace 1 here</div>
<br>
<label>Editor2:</label>
<div ui-ace="{
  useWrapMode : false,
  showGutter: false,
  theme:'monokai',
  mode: 'javascript'
}" ng-model="editor2">Ace 2 here</div>
<br>
<label>Editor3:</label>
<div ui-ace="{
  useWrapMode : false,
  showGutter: false,
  theme:'monokai',
  mode: 'javascript'
}" ng-model="editor3">Ace 3 here</div>
<br>
<label>Editor4:</label>
<div ui-ace="{
  useWrapMode : false,
  showGutter: false,
  theme:'monokai',
  mode: 'javascript'
}" ng-model="editor4">Ace 4 here</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

After researching this further it turns out that the ui-ace plunker demos are using an ace.js version that causes this weird scroll behavior when multiple code editors are used.  Instead of using `<script src="https://rawgithub.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/v1.1.1/src-min-noconflict/ace.js"></script>` in your demos you can use the ace.js version here https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-ace/vendor/ace.js or even better you can use `<script src="https://rawgithub.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/master/src-min/ace.js"></script>`

If you view the page source to http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-ace/ and click on `vendor/ace.js` you can confirm that they are using http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-ace/vendor/ace.js whereas their plunker demos use https://rawgithub.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/v1.1.1/src-min-noconflict/ace.js

```
<!-- Le javascript
================================================== -->
<script src="assets/vendor/prettify.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="core/prettifyDirective.js"></script>
<script src="core/plunker.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/ace.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/theme-twilight.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/mode-markdown.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/mode-scheme.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/worker-javascript.js"></script>
<script src="dist/ui-ace.min.js"></script>
```

working plunker is here https://plnkr.co/E7Dl2btYJFWpms0mdVE0